# Keep module name in url of hmvc codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I have integrated hmvc in codeigniter 3.1.*. I have multiple modules locations so now  i want url configuration like

`http://host_name/module_location_name/module_name/controller/method`

In details,

I have create two module_locations under **application** directory.

1) application/admin/users/registration/signup

2) application/customer/users/registration/listing

Now Urls should be 
http://host_name/admin/users/registration/signup
http://host_name/customer/users/registration/listing

how I can achieve this??

Comment: Is `http://host_name/admin/customer/users/registration/listing` url correct? don't you mean `http://host_name/customer/users/registration/listing`?

Comment: sorry my mistake. you are right. I updated question.